# Netlify generating invalid code in local mode

Tags: javascript, netlify

When I issue the `netlify serve` command, a routine (`remix-server.mjs`) is generated that contains the following statements:

```
import { default as default2 } from "....\buildserverserver.js";

// The import statement above was copied from below and this 
// comment was added to explain what I did 

import {createRequire as ___nfyCreateRequire} from "module";
import {fileURLToPath as ___nfyFileURLToPath} from "url";
import {dirname as ___nfyPathDirname} from "path";
let __filename=___nfyFileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
let      __dirname=___nfyPathDirname(___nfyFileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
let require=___nfyCreateRequire(import.meta.url);


// .netlify/functions-internal/remix-server.mjs
import { default as default2 } from "....\buildserverserver.js";
var config = {
  name: "Remix server handler",
  generator: "@netlify/remix-adapter@2.3.0",
  path: "/*",
  preferStatic: true
};
export {
  config,
  default2 as default
};
```

That's wrong. The imported `buildserverserver.js` file does not exist. The code generator is making some type of mistake.

Has anyone seen this error? How should I fix it in local/remote mode?

Comment: Please share the relevant source code as well

Comment: This is a reply to Chinz. I am not sure what to post. I have posted the complete contents of .netlify/functions serve/.unzipped/remix-server/remix-server.mjs. Does that help?