# How do I create and run a Netlify/Remix project?

Tags: netlify, remix.run, netlify-cli

This question is an extension of [my Netlify question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78164915).

I followed the default Netlify-Remix instructions over at [Remix on Netlify](https://docs.netlify.com/frameworks/remix/). I created a Netlify/Remix project using the specified template (`npx create-remix@latest --template netlify/remix-template`). I then followed the instructions in the README file.

This yielded an error: `Invalid module "...buildserverserver.js" is not a valid package name`. Note that `netlify dev` works, but `netlify serve` fails. Why does this error occur?